# Copy entire table copies only first 1000 rows in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Power BI Desktop, office 365. 32bit, Win 10.

I have 25k rows table in PowerQuery that is producing something weird, and I need to check in Excel to be sure. I am trying to use Copy Entire Table option but it only copies 1000 rows.

I believe I can scroll down all the way, but I really can't be scrolling down to 25r rows, each scroll takes absolute ages because the table is derived as a unique list based on 15m sales fact table.

A year ago when I worked with Power Query in Excel (not Power Bi desktop), this was not a problem. Not with this amount of data anyway, 25k should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

i found an answer on powerBI community, basically need to pull the table into a visual and from there, can export all data into a file.